# SQL get max in table with COUNT

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

```
SELECT a.FirstName, a.LastName, Count(cai.ArtistID)
FROM Artist a
JOIN CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT cai ON(a.ArtistID=cai.ArtistID)
GROUP BY a.FirstName, a.LastName
```

Gives me an output of

```
FirstName    LastName     COUNT(CAI.ArtistID)
Luke         Skywalker    2
Han          Solo         7
Darth        Vader        3
```

However, my query must only give me the one with the highest Count thus the output should be:

```
FirstName    LastName    COUNT(CAI.ArtistID)
Han          Solo        7
```

I know I have to put the MAX function but i have no idea how.

Answer (score 1):

you can use top 1 order by desc as below

```
SELECT top (1) a.FirstName, a.LastName, Count(cai.ArtistID)
FROM Artist a
JOIN CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT cai ON (a.ArtistID=cai.ArtistID)
GROUP BY a.FirstName, a.LastName
order by count(cai.Artistid) desc
```

If you are looking for certain category you might require to use row_number

Comment: Hi, could you clarify, I tried to run it but it gave me the error
FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: yours is mysql or sql server? both are two different db engines

Comment: Oracle SQL developer

Comment: updated with parenthesis on join condition... can you check?